# Way to restart the service from controller when data(here url) changes, in Angular

Tags: angularjs, http, service, controller, httprequest

What is the right approach to get my http request to run again and give new result when I have a new url?

I tried to wrap the whole http call inside another function and call that function from thecontroller. I also tried to run `fac.success` again. But nothing worked. Thanks for any pointers.

```
app.factory('fac', ['$http', function(http) { 
    return http.get(url)
    .success(function(result) { 
        return result;})
    .error(function(err) { 
        return err; });
}]);
```

Comment: Shouldn't `http` within your function parameter be `$http`?

Comment: Check the post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31408564/angular-http-difference-between-success-and-then

Comment: @tylerwal, $http is passed into the function as any argument, so the argument is available for use inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return data in your `success` and `error` handlers. The `$http` call is asynchronous, so the callback functions are called when the promise is resolved...but returning the data to your service after it has run would have no effect.

Instead, consider injecting `$http` into your controller and calling it from there.

**EDIT**

Following up on my comment, `$http` itself is a service, so unless you are doing something more than just making a call, it doesn't make sense to wrap it in another service. Just use the $http service in your controller, like this:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('MyController', MyController);

MyController.$inject = ['$http'];
function MyController($http) {
    $http.get('http://path.to.api/')
        .then(function(res) { /* handle success */ })
        .catch(function(err) { /* handle error */ });
}
```

However, if you want to provide a service that makes a call and caches the response, you could write a service for that. Something like this...

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('myDataService', myDataServiceFactory);

myDataServiceFactory.$inject = ['$http', '$cacheFactory', '$q'];
function myDataServiceFactory($http, $cacheFactory, $q) {
    var cache = $cacheFactory('myData');

    return {
        getData: getData,
    };

    function getData(url) {
        var data = cache.get(url);
        if (data) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve(data);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
        var promise = $http.get(url);
        promise.then(function(res) {
            cache.put(url, res);
        });
        return promise;
    }
}
```

...but that example is kind of silly, because `$http` already offers a [configuration for caching](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#caching) response data.

Comment: Using a $http again inside the controller worked. Thanks. I was puzzled because the purpose of the service is to separate communication logic. And 'fac.success' returns the right result first.                                                     But to do an other http call, it has to be done again.

Comment: No, you only use $http in your controller. Your service as written is useless, because it makes the request but those callbacks do nothing. Using $http in your controller is the correct way to do it, because the controller knows what to do with the response. Only reason to wrap it in a service is if you are caching the response and want to make that data available via your service.

Answer (score 0):

> ### Deprecation Notice
>
> The `$http` legacy promise methods `.success` and `.error` have been deprecated. Use the standard `.then` method instead.<sup>[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice)</sup>

```
app.factory('fac', ['$http', function(http) { 
    return (
        http.get(url).then( function onFulfilled (result) {
            //return data for chaining 
            return result.data;
        }).catch( function onRejected(response) {
            console.log(result.status);
            //throw to chain rejection  
            throw result;
        })
    );
}]);
```